# Dropbox not working after installation in ubuntu 16.04.2 lts

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

after installation I am not being able to use Dropbox...after installation I got the prompt to restart nautilus..but pressing the restart button of the nautilus is not working...after signing in the browser, files are open in browser but not on the computer home drive...

Answer (score 1):

Update: Start dropbox with `dropbox start -i`

Edit from the man page:

```
dropbox start [-i]
    Starts the dropbox daemon, dropboxd. If dropboxd is already running, this will do nothing.

    options:

    -i --install auto install dropboxd if not available on the system
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question before fiddling with other options but eventually I found the answer after tinkering number of times. If the Nautilus restart does not work, just close the prompt then close the dropbox from the status bar. Reboot/ restart the computer and sign in to your dropbox account. Voila! It worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install from `terminal`.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add following line at end of file

```
deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily main
```

Now Save and Exit.

> import Dropbox GPG key to your Ubuntu 16.04 system.

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 1C61A2656FB57B7E4DE0F4C1FC918B335044912E
```

Now update package list and install Dropbox.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dropbox python-gpgme
```

> Start dropbox with  `dropbox start`

Now popup will appear click "OK" and you all done.